# Норовистый, сноровистый и своенравный

Tags: лексика

Три названных прилагательных имеют один и тот же корень норов/нрав со значением "характер", но при этом возникают следующие вопросы (см. примеры):

1) Своенравный и норовистый - это одно и то же?

2) Откуда у слов "сноровка,  сноровистый" появилось значение "ловкий"?

3) Почему норовистый бывает "тихим, нежным"?

ПРИМЕРЫ

Жизнь в Гремячем Логу стала на дыбы, как норовистый конь перед трудным препятствием (М. А. Шолохов).

Тот не захотел ждать, норовистый был мужик, хваткий и своенравный (Михаил Тарковский).

Там хошь и плохо небо видно, да я все по привычке смотрела. И дожжик такой норовистый, тихий. Ой, думаю, че-то неладно (Валентин Распутин)

Удивительный щенок, нежный, норовистый, умница.

А Чонкин, она приглядела, парень сноровистый и с ухваткой, для хозяйства, сразу видно, полезный (Владимир Войнович).

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры 2 и 3 действительно совершенно противоречат остальным где "норовистый" означает непокорный, своенравный, и т.п. Как неспециалист могу только предположить что "норовистый" в этих случаях созвучно "нравиться", т.е. то, что по нраву, настроению, в лад. Про дождь ведь ещё говорят "дождь заладил".

И здесь удивительным образом просматривается ответ на #2: ловкость, сноровка, лад, ладно, гладко, привычно, умело.

Скорее всего этот вопрос вас уже не интересует, но здешний бот его почему-то подбросил... может быть, искусственный разум захотел больше узнать о природе нашей нелогичности :)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.

*Предупреждение: не являюсь специалистом, всё написанное ниже - исключительно личное мнение, основанное на внутренних ощущениях много читающего "хомо частично-местами-где-то-даже-сапиенса". Пишу только потому, что других ответов нет вообще уже восемь дней.*

1. Похоже, что да, если судить по описанию этих слов в Викисловаре.
2. Извините, не знаю.
3. Из третьего примера можно сделать вывод, что слово "норовистый" употребляется вместе с прилагательными "тихий, нежный" для придания всему описанию того же смысла, что изложен в пословице "в тихом омуте черти водятся". То есть несмотря на то, что описываемый объект внешне безопасный, "тихий", но есть что-то, что заставляет от него ожидать каких-либо неожиданных действий. 
   Четвёртый пример можно перефразировать так: "умница, потому что несмотря на норовистость, ведёт себя нежно и ласково, не даёт волю буйному нраву".

С уважением, Владимир.

Comment: Спасибо, Владимир за внимание к моему вопросу, других пользователей он не заинтересовал.  Мне тоже казалось, что норовистый и своенравный - это одно и то же, но странно, что оба слова употреблены в одном предложении. Кажется, что своенравный - это одно из качеств норовистого. А вот норовистый в компании с тихим и нежным наводят на мысль, что одно из значений "норовистого"  не дошло до современного языка или является диалектным.

Answer (score 0):

1. Слова *норовистый* и *своенравный* можно рассматривать как синонимы, но оттенки у них разные: первое значит "упрямый, с крутым нравом", а второе ближе к "своеобразный, своевольный", где-то даже "сумасбродный, капризный". Дабы лучше понять, попробуйте сравнить слова "волевой" и "своевольный": в одном речь о степени проявлении качества, а в другом больше о направлении проявления, а именно в угоду себе.
2. *Сноровка* <— *сноравливание* <- *сноровить/сноравливать*, то есть "приладить в пору и в меру" (по Далю). *Сноровка* — это умение сладить, уладить, приладить, сделать так, чтобы понравилось, было по нраву.
3. В слове *нравиться* тот же корень, что и в слове *норовистый*. Можно предположить, что *норовистый* — это такой, который нравится или стремится понравиться, угодливый.